# Custom Razor View Engine in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing some prototyping in .NET 5 MVC 6 and am trying to figure out where to register my custom razor view engine.  MVC  6 no longer has a global.asax file to do your registration of custom objects.  It does have a startup.cs file which I would assume would be the place to add it, but I am unsure if this is the right place to do this and what method to call.

I current have custom razor view engine that looks something like

```
public class MyCustomerViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyCustomerViewEngine()
    {
        //My custom view stuff
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *Startup.cs* file

Go to `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddMvc(); // Replace this with following

services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewEngines.Add(new MyCustomerViewEngine ());
});
```

Comment: Make sure you include `using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`.  It's there by default but if you did a remove and sort usings it would have been removed. :(